# Custom image for UINavigation Back Button in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I have a custom `UIBarButtonItem` with an image that works fine in iOS 6.1. But iOS 7 has a `tintColor` and it overlays this color over my image. If I set the `tintColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]` the button doesn't show up all together.

How can I have my back button show up in iOS 7 as it does in iOS 6? Please help?

[image: iOS 6.1]

[image: iOS 7]

Comment: You should not use a bar button item as a back button. Instead set the `backIndicatorImage` for the navigation bar.

Comment: The app has to have the same look in all iOS versions. `backIndicatorImage` is for iOS 7 only. I already use a `mask` in iOS 6 

`const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors([[UIImage alloc] init].CGImage, colorMask)];

    [backButtonItem setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: I am using ios5, can U help me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to set `UIBarButtonItem` like this way in ios7:-

```
UIImage *temp = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];    
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:temp style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(action)];
```

Here is an original post in apple Dev center [discussion Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/873178#873178)

For supporting both version iOS7 as well as lower then you check `system-version` and set code like:-

```
UIImage *temp=nil;

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
{ 
    temp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"]; 
}
else
{ 
    temp = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` doesn't work in iOS 6, I had to make a check for the iOS version. `UIImage *backImage = nil;

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0){
        backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"];

    }else{
        backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    }`

Comment: thank you i just edit my answer for supporting both Version to help's other they stuck with same issue.

Comment: also a minor thing, you should drop the .png in your images. that way ios can pick up retina and non retina images, or device specific images as well.

Comment: I believe respondsToSelector: would be more appropriate in this case. 

UIImage *temp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back.png"]; 
if ([temp respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)])
 { 
temp = [temp imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]; 
}

Comment: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered is deprecated in iOS8.x. Use UIBarButtonItemStylePlain.

Answer (score 43):

You should use appearance on UINavigationBar to globally set the custom back button.

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorImage = customBackButton;
[UINavigationBar appearance].backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = customBackButton;
```

Comment: I would like to add that customBackButton image should use `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`, like this `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];` so it can show the color of the image.

Comment: Not valid for iOS 9: no  backIndicatorImage

Comment: @Sebastian You are right, fixed and forgot about that. Likely had typo there and autocompletion didn't work. Thanks for noting that!

Comment: How to remove title in all back button when appearance?

Comment: Xcode/Swift don't seem to know about these as they don't show in autocomplete, it compiles and runs though.

Answer (score 20):

The following seems to make a bit more sense for people who don't want to mess with the existing target action, etc. Just copy and paste. Also this forces iOS to use *your* image with all of its flairs -- as opposed to simply using a template/impression of the image.

```
- (void)setCustomNavigationBackButton
{
    UIImage *backBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];
    backBtn = [backBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backBtn;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backBtn;
}
```

`arrow` is the name of your image.

Answer (score 8):

swift version:

```
var backBtn = UIImage(named: "return_menu")
backBtn = backBtn?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backBtn;
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backBtn;
```

Comment: It was not working until I added "imageWithRenderingMode"...thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try it this way:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"];
```

This will create an image mask in the global tint colour which will give you your own custom icon. Does not work for colour images.

Answer (score 0):

// ADDING IMAGE TO BUTTON

```
UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[refreshButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
refreshButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// ASSIGNING THE BUTTON WITH IMAGE TO BACK BAR BUTTON

UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:refreshButton] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshBarButton;
```