# How to hide back button title on iOS7 with NavigationController

Tags: ios7, navigationcontroller

I have a NavigationController based iOS7 app , on this I want to hide the back button text which is displayed along with the chevron. Is there a way out to  this ? I tried setting empty string to the back button title , tried empty title on previous view as well seems like if it finds empty title it replaces that with "Back" text.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to see the chevron/back arrow without any text or do you want to hide the back button completely? The former is a bad idea (IMHO, unless you need the additional space), the later has been answered multiple times already here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DarkDust yes i need more space due to some reason.

Comment: So you've tried using `@""` (`nil` won't work, that will give you "Back")? What about `@" "` (a single space)?

Comment: Yes tried spaces not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 navigation bar custom back button without title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870128/ios-7-navigation-bar-custom-back-button-without-title)

Comment: Also, this might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912638/custom-image-for-uinavigation-back-button-in-ios-7

Comment: @DarkDust first link has some answers they helped, but not all of them work lol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45905/discussion-between-vishal-and-darkdust)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally ended up solving it as follows , this one worked perfect.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
```

from this link [Removing the title text of an iOS UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078995/removing-the-title-text-of-an-ios-7-uibarbuttonitem)

But if you navigate from previous view to next view you can see that the title of the previous view navigation bar vanishes when i put the above mentioned solution in viewDidDisappear of viewWillDisappear of previous view, which isn't an elegant solution in storyboard based UINavigationController scenario , in another situation i finally decided to use a bar button and set its image as per the native back button chevron, this gives better results.

Comment: I posted a different answer below to address the drawback you mentioned about the title vanishing...

Answer (score 9):

The answer proposed by @vishal has a serious drawback: it removes the title from controller A if you navigate back from A to B.

Here is a safer solution to apply on controller A before pushing controller B:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

And for swift:

```
if let topItem = controller.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem {
    topItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide back button title into all your app, put this in you App Delegate:

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (myCustomization)

-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
}

@end
```

tested on iOS 7

Comment: This is awesome. Works like a charm to make sure that ALL back buttons in the app have just the arrow and no text.

Answer (score 1):

For hide the back button of navigation controller ,try this one:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:nil];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
```

may it will help you.

happy coding...:)

Comment: This is not what I asked for , I was asking about how to hide the title not the entire button.

Comment: @vishal for that you have to hide whole back button and added custom button with uiimage if you want then i put code?

Comment: Nope that's not the approach i can follow as I have lots of views

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove the back button title with

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

in `viewWillAppear` on the presenting view controller. Note, **presenting** not presented.

From [Removing the title text of an iOS UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23465052/1514022).