# Possible to create back button like this in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to have a navigation bar like this:

[image]

I tried using this image:
[image]

And using this code:

```
homeVC.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bb"];
homeVC.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bb"];
```

And the result is...not so good:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve an effect similar to the above?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Nav bar's height seems off. It's 92px at the moment. 2. Your back indicator image lacks the gray overlay around itself to set it's boundaries and darken the below color.

Comment: @Desdenova that what I am confused about. What should be the size of the back indicator image? and does it include the dark color below? Or is that some other method that accepts a 'backbground image' ?

Comment: @Desdenova ignore the height of nav bar. I just screen shotted them so it might be a little inaccruate.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a limit to it. Based on your screenshot with slight inaccuracy, a 100x88 px image should do.

Comment: @Desdenova the problem is that the back text (in this case 'TODY;S 15) over lap. It comes on top of the back image. That's what leads me to think there's a particular size that I need to use. Looking at the documentation, there's no mention of this though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom image for UINavigation Back Button in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912638/custom-image-for-uinavigation-back-button-in-ios-7)

Comment: So much for the transparent area around the image theory. Seems like that's been changed as well. There is a inset going on around the button, that's ruining the desired affect. Had to use a solid color 88x88 image to see that.

Comment: So what's the right size? I tried 88x88 and that doesn't work.